# C# MySQL query result Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, arraylist

```
public ArrayList P2a(string sql)
{
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    MySqlConnection mysqlconnection = new MySqlConnection(xxx);
    cmd.Connection = mysqlconnection;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (int count = 0; (count <= (reader.FieldCount - 1)); count++)
            {
                dict.Add(reader.GetName(count), reader[count]);
            }
                result.Add(dict);
        }

        return result;
    } catch {
        return result;
    } finally {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

C# Visual Studio 2017 MySQL void return echo problem.

I want to make sure that I print out the result properly.

Example:

```
ArrayList query = P2a("select id,site,comment from sites");

MessageBox.Show(query[0]["site"].toString());
```

To use it this way.

Can you make the necessary corrections in the function?

Comment: What issue you are facing with that code? Did you debug the code to check if there is any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself

I wrote a new function

```
  public DataTable query(string sql) {

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection connection = null;
            MySqlDataReader reader = null;

            try {
                connection = new MySqlConnection(xxx);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);

                return table;
            } catch {
                return table;
            } finally {

                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();
            }}
```

use off

```
DataTable list = query("select * from tablename");

MessageBox.Show(list.Rows["rowsname"]["cellname"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend as a start to change your catch block.

1. You should be throwing the exception, ideally with more information.
2. I also recommend that you have an optional list of MySqlParameters (defaults to null), while its not obvious here, since there are no parameters, more than likely you have SQL that is suspectible to SQL injection.  In most cases, if you have a where block and its not null, you have done something incorrectly.
3. Your code does not cleanup the disposable objects, so using will take care of that.
4. Use generics instead as the list item will now be a dictionary.

   ```
   public List<Dictionary<String, object>> P2a(string sql, MySqlParameter[] parameters)
   {
       List<Dictionary<String, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<String, object>>();

       using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
       {
           using (MySqlConnection mysqlconnection = new MySqlConnection(xxx))
           {
               cmd.Connection = mysqlconnection;
               cmd.CommandText = sql;

               if (parameters != null)
               {
                   foreach (MySqlParameter p in parameters)
                   {
                       cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                   }
               }

               try
               {
                   cmd.Connection.Open();
                   using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                   {
                       while (reader.Read())
                       {
                           Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                           for (int count = 0; (count <= (reader.FieldCount - 1)); count++)
                           {
                               dict.Add(reader.GetName(count), reader[count]);
                           }
                           result.Add(dict);
                       }
                   }

                   return result;
               }
               catch (ApplicationException ex)
               {
                   throw new ApplicationException("Error Executing " + sql, ex);
               }
               finally
               {
                   cmd.Connection.Close();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Queries from MySQL database which can transfer a variable like php Could you create a function?

Comment: thats a different question than what was asked...if the answer is acceptable...please accept and post the question separately